# Windows Phone 8 call WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have been tasked with writing a WP8 application that needs to link to a WCF web service but I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong

I can't change the WCF service, it's not mine

The method I am struggling with takes a class as a parameter and returns a different class as the result

The interface I have been given for a test method is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "TestLogin")]
TestResults TestLogin(TestDetails Test);

public class TestDetails
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}

public string TestResult
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public List<TestOrders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried RestSharp but I just get a bad request

Any advice will be much appreciated

Here's my sample code:

```
var client = new RestClient
{
        BaseUrl = "http://www.testing.co.uk/Services/Service.svc"
};

var dto = new TestDetails
{
    username = "abc",
    password = "123",
    DeviceId = String.Empty,
    DeviceModel = String.Empty
};

var request = new RestRequest
{
    Resource = "Testlogin",
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
    Method = Method.POST
};

request.AddParameter("TestDetails", dto, ParameterType.RequestBody);
// request.AddBody(dto);
var response = client.Post<TestResult>(request);
```

Comment: What's not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I just get back "bad request"

Comment: Can you use a tool like Fiddler to simulate the requests, or watch a request that works and see what's different about it from what you're sending?

Comment: I've tried that but I can't get my request to work, even fiddler says bad request.  I know their API works because their Android app works

Comment: Is it a documented API? Can you get help from the owners of the API?

Comment: I've tried that :-(   I have even written my own wcf service exactly as above, put it in the cloud and get the same error

Comment: Have you looked at the Android application's network traffic? Is this a published API?

Comment: I don't know how to look at the Android's network traffic :-(  No it's a private API

Comment: Ok. Normally you'd install a proxy.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try and figure out how to look at the Android traffic

Comment: can u give me an idea how to use wcf with android device. @cjp666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured it out :-)  I've switched to using HttpClient

```
public static void Testing()
{
    var c = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.testing.co.uk/Services/Service.svc/")
    };
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var json = "{\"login\":{\"DeviceId\":\"\",\"Password\":\"123\",\"Username\":\"abc\",\"DeviceModel\":\"\"}}";

    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "TestLogin")
    {
        Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
    c.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(respTask =>
    {
        var response = respTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", respTask.Result);
    });
}
```

Comment: if I have method name as GetOrder(string) then what should I write instead of application/json and "Test Login"